# Symfony Messenger does not consume messages until stop/consume

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq, amqp, messenger

On Symfony 5.1, I created two very basic message classes.
The first updates the database and then it calls the other to send a mail via SwiftMailer.

**Both of them arrive to the consumer command** as they are logged by the `bin/console messenger:consume async -vv` command, but while the class that updates the database is handled, the other remains *suspended*.

The fact is that **if I stop and restart the consume command**, this message becomes handled by the consumer and so the mail is sent.

I have tried with Redis and RabbitMQ transports, with the very same results.

This is the messenger configuration:

```
framework:
  messenger:
    transports:
      async:
        dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'

    routing:
      'App\Message\FollowRequestMessage': async
      'App\Message\EmailMessage': async
```

This is the MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN in .env:

```
MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:5672/%2f/messages
```

**UPDATE**

I defined another transport to handle the FollowRequest and Email messages separately, by duplicating the "async" transport config in the yaml messenger configuration.

This has fixed the issue, but I don't know if it the right way to handle the case.

So, it is correct to create a different transport for each kind of message? Or is it a workaround because of an error in something else?

Comment: I believe you should elaborate on the logic of your app. I have yet to understand, what you mean by "suspend", would you elaborate? the messenger and queues have their own language, but "suspend" isn't part of it. how do you even "suspend" a message? and why is that your approach? why doesn't the first handler produce the second message? since that dependency appears to exist, it's illogical to produce the second message beforehand, unless the necessity is explained to some degree

Comment: I wrote suspend in italics because it is an unexpected behaviour to me too. With suspended I mean it is sent to the queue manager, but it is not handled by the consume worker. If I restart this worker, the message is finally handled.
The workaround I'm using at the moment is to restart the worker after it handles just one message.

Comment: I think you should create 2 transports: one for each message handler